# How to push Helm Charts to Azure Container Registry using Drone?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, drone.io, azure-container-registry

Could someone please give me some pointers on how to push/pull Helm charts to Azure Container Registry using Drone, whether its possible or not?

I could not find any documentation regarding that.

Comment: have you had a look at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-helm-repos, you should be able to use a exec pipeline in Drone to push your chart after you enable the repos in your ACR

Comment: I did, though it looks like cumbersome process if to be used with Drone. On top of that it needs azure cli.

Comment: also it would mean I will have to have helm binaries somehow in drone

Comment: to me its all expected.  with any CI tool, you will have to add the required binary to handled the artifact format you want to produce

Comment: I'm not clear that you want to push/pull Helm charts to ACR using Drone without Helm tool? You do not want t use any tool?